# timecodestamper has no property named 'set'

Tags: timestamp, gstreamer, h.264

I am using gstreamer to stream over UDP (using RTP) a video from a camera and I would like to add timestamps in the H264 metadata.
I have tried to add timecodestamper in the pipeline like this:

```c
GstElement *timestamp;
timestamp = gst_element_factory_make ("timecodestamper", "myTimeStamp");
g_object_set (timestamp, "set", "always", "source", "rtc", NULL);
```

And then I add it to the pipeline, but I have this warning:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:34:01.208: g_object_set_is_valid_property:
object class 'GstTimeCodeStamper' has no property named 'set'
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an older GStreamer version.

The `set` property was added in GStreamer 1.17.1.

- [New API documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/timecode/timecodestamper.html?gi-language=c)
- [Old API documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-timecodestamper.html)

You can also use `gst-inspect timecodestamper` on your local system to see documentation relevant to the installed version.

For the old version, the equivalent property of `set=always` is `override-existing=true`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed I am using GStreamer 1.14.5 so I will use  override-existing=true as you suggested.